# A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server error on update command - “A severe error occurred on the current command”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-com)

I'm getting an error using SQL Server 2005 stored procedure.

> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded."

I have a stored proc which saves a record. As far as I can tell this error gets thrown when that procedure gets called too many times in quick succession, or maybe simultaneously by different threads

The proc is very simple, it does a BEGIN TRY.. BEGIN TRAN... IF NOT EXISTS INSERT .. ELSE UPDATE .. COMMIT TRAN .. END TRY

No SQLDUMP file gets created, and nothing gets written into ERRORLOG.

It is a Severity 11 error. The SqlException does not contain State or Number

SQL Server 2005 SP3 (9.00.4035)

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

There is an hot fix avaliable by microsoft
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910416