# SQL Server Exception "A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded"

Tags: sql-server

Can somebody help me get through the following Sql Exception : "A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded".

I'm running a drop replication (i.e sp_dropsubscription & sp_droparticle) script reading from the uploaded file using c#.net. I encounter the above error when running in Sql server 2008, but the same thing works fine in Sql Server 2005.

At the point of the Exception, I see that the Commands have actually got executed in the backend but can't figure out why the exception. Any idea ??

Thanks.

Comment: Does it not say which severe error occurred; there are lots and they all have a different meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server error on update command - "A severe error occurred on the current command"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-comm)