# PRINT from nested stored procedure causes "A severe error occurred on the current command."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Calling `PRINT` from a child stored procedure causes:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

How to make it not give an error?

**Note:** [*Not* SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-comm/1175725#1175725)

---

i have a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Archive_SessionDeleteOnly] AS

  SET XACT_ABORT ON

  BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
  EXECUTE ASILIVE.ContosoLive.dbo.Archive_Delete 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  PRINT 'Fargodeep Mine'
```

With the child stored procedure being:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Archive_Delete] AS

  PRINT 'You no take candle'
```

When i run my outer procedure `Archive_SessionDeleteOnly` it all runs to completion, including the `PRINT` *after* the call to my child stored procedure

```
You no take candle
Fargodeep Mine
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

The entire operation runs to completion, but i get an error:

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

If i remove the `print` from the "child" stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Archive_Delete] AS
  --PRINT 'You no take candle'
```

it runs without error.

i've also tried randomly adding `NOCOUNT` (since nobody knows how to fix it anyway):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Archive_Delete] AS

  SET NOCOUNT ON
  PRINT 'You no take candle'
```

it still causes:

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

ServerA: SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT @@version
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.818 (Intel X86)   May 31 2003 16:08:15   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

ServerB: SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT @@version
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2055 (Intel X86)   Dec 16 2008 19:46:53   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

There are no errors in either SQL Server Error Log.

How can i make SQL Server not choke when a `PRINT` is used in a child stored procedure. i have other cases where i call print from child stored procedures, without error.

**Update** Trimmed down to minimal reproducible case. Exact sql is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with SQL 2000 when the query is run from Management Studio

Have you tried running it in Query Analyzer?

Comment: i dug out a version of QA. You're right. Who would have thought it's a bug in SSMS.