# A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

For the past couple of days, I have been getting quite a bit of the messages below with no clue how to fix them. I use temp tables in many of my procedures for processing.

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0. A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded

All my stored procedures have `NO COUNT` set to `ON`. I don't use a whole lot of CTEs and I drop all temp tables after use.

I checked the log files `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.WORKBOX\MSSQL\Log` but found nothing that I believe explains what is happening to me. I would appreciate any help tackling this issue please.

Comment: Any specific script on which you get this error? Could you put in your question?

Comment: Also - does your Common Table Expression (CTE) query use the Freetexttable or Containstable function on an indexed view - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2421014

Comment: Not a specific Script, as I ran the same script(s) successfully only minutes before this error started showing up on subsequent runs. And no, my CTEs don't use FREETEXTABLE, nor do they contain table functions on an indexed view.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: People have the same error caused by multiple different issues. 

Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-com