# Stored Procedure not showing in Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssms

In one of my databases, when I am tring to view the list of user created stored procedures under the Programmability --> Stored Procedures, it pops up the below error.

" A severe error occured on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded."

I can view the System stored procedures under System stored procedures.

I took a backup of this database and restored to another server. The restored database also have same issue.

The stored procedure are showing in sys.Procedures and sp_helptext retrieves the procedure structure as well.

Any help will be highly appreciated

N.B : There are other 50 databases in the same server and there is no issue with those databases. The procedures are properly listed under the stored procedures

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-com

Comment: restart sql management studio

Comment: Also, you should check on that error if it persists. SQL Server has an event history that might be helpful. If it persists, your instance might be corrupted.

Comment: I found a procedure exists in sys.procedures and sys.allobjects.

The issue is that sp_helptext will not give the structure for this procedure. When I try  to drop this procedure , it says the procedure no longer exists.   I tried to remove from sys.allobjects but it says "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out what was causing this issue. One of the procedures that existed in the database was dropped in the past. Unfortunately, for some reason, the traces of the procedure still exists in some system tables like Sys.Objects.

Whenever, I expand the Stored Procedures, the SSMS is trying to pull the details of the this procedure also, which was already dropped(does not exist in Sys.Procedures anymore).

This cause the error to pop up.

From my months of research what I understood is in later versions of SQL Server, the users will not be having the access to modify the System tables like sys.objects. So there is no way around for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Run profiler before open procedure list. the next open procedure list and investigate a last queries in profiler.