# SQL Server: error when creating a # temp table

Tags: sql-server

When I try to create a `#temp` table, I get this:

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Any ideas how to solve this error? Thank you!

Comment: Show some code please otherwise I'm just going to assume you didn't program it right

Comment: CREATE TABLE  #TEMP (ID Bigint). I get the error when i try to create a temp table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server error on update command - "A severe error occurred on the current command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-com)

Comment: No Error found when i run this .

CREATE TABLE #TEMP (ID Bigint);
select * from #TEMP;
delete #TEMP;

Answer (score 1):

In one of my `update` queries, I had the same problem. I realized that the problem was from memory leakage.

Restarting `MSSQL` service will flush `tempDb` resource and free a large amount of memory. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL SERVER – Msg 0, Level 11 – A Severe Error Occurred on the Current Command. The results, if Any, Should be Discarded**

**CHECKLIST for this error**

First and foremost, check database consistency. This can be done by running below command in SQL Server

```
DBCC CHECKDB('database_name');
```

If you have nailed down to a table, then check table consistency. We can execute below command

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE('table_name');
```

Check the LOG folder which contains ERRORLOG and look for any file named ‘SQLDump*’ at the same time when the error was reported. If you find any, you can either contact Microsoft or use the self-service by getting dump analyzed using diagnostic preview.

If you are getting this while using extended stored procedure, then you need to run, debug by running the exact piece of code one by one. Here is one such error which had none of 3 causes.

In case you want to see the error yourself, feel free to use below code

```
create table #ErrorLog (column1 char(8000))
go
insert into #ErrorLog
exec xp_readerrorlog 'SQL Error'
drop table #ErrorLog
```

Reference: Pinal Dave (https://blog.sqlauthority.com)