# Can't Drop Azure SQL Table due to severe error, what is the cause?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to drop a table before reading in a new set of values for testing purposes. When I run the command

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
```

I get the following error after about 3-5 minutes. It is a large table (~50 million rows).

> Failed to execute query. Error: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
> Operation cancelled by user.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-com/3514273#3514273)

Comment: Yes, I tried re-indexing already and received the same error. I actually tried that before making this post. I ran the test as well and it ran successfully but nothing was output.

Comment: Try truncating the table instead

Comment: Run the below script and check if any blocking session is there 
`SELECT  session_id
     ,blocking_session_id
     ,wait_time
     ,wait_type
     ,last_wait_type
     ,wait_resource
     ,transaction_isolation_level
     ,lock_timeout
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
    WHERE blocking_session_id <> 0`

Comment: It ended up being a VPN issue, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to execute query. Error: A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation cancelled by user. what is the cause?

The error can cause for many different reasons, but it is not showing exact reason to find exact reason you can check following things:

- It might be because of indexing issue to get that check the consistency of the database should be checked first

```sql
DBCC CHECKDB(``'database_name'``);
```

Check table consistency if you have it nailed down to a table.

```sql
DBCC CHECKTABLE(``'table_name'``);
```

- When the problem was reported, search for any files with the name `SQLDump*` in the LOG folder, which contains **ERRORLOG** or You can try following actions in SSMS:

> **Object Explorer >> Management Node >> SQL Server Logs >> View the current log**